# How do you add more options to a select2 <select> using jquery?

Tags: bootstrap-4, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

I was having the same challenge and i found [official select2 documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items) very useful.

I tried this`$('#selectBox').append($('<option>').val(optionValue).text(optionText))` but it was auto selecting the value after adding it

Answer (score 1):

**You should try this:**

```
newOption = New Option(optionValue,OptionValue,true,true);
$('#selectBox').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```